# How can JSON with an empty key be parsed into NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, xcode

I get a JSON response, that contains an empty key (""):

```
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "Wrong email and password combination"
        ]
    }
}
```

Can this JSON be properly parsed into NSDictionary using JSONKit?

Comment: It will probably parse it into a zero-length NSString. The functional equivalent of @"". However, since JSONKit is fairly small and open source, just take a look at the implementation and see what it actually does. I'd be stunned if it did anything other than return @"", however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were the data portion and you were using TouchJSON, it would typically get interpreted as null and set as an NSNull object in the dictionary rather than an NSString.  (you can compare to [NSNull null]).

Not sure what happens with JSONKit or whether it being a key rather than a value would make any difference to this (I would assume not, but if its interpreted as NSNull key and there are multiple null keys this would I assume create some issues).

EDIT: Jason is correct with his comment below.  NSNull is only set if there is a null value on the object - an empty string is set as an empty string in the dictionary.  If the key value is an empty string then the dictionary has an object with a key of @""  (and it can be retrieved thus
    [myDictionary objectForKey:@""];

Note this is all in TouchJSON

Comment: That would be invalid JSON parsing... if a value is a pair of double quotes with nothing inside, it is an empty string. The only JSON value that should be converted to the NSNull instance would be the literal string `null` with no quotes.

Comment: You may be correct about it being invalid JSON parsing, but I seem to recall this being the behaviour of touchJSON when a value has an empty string - maybe my memory in this regard is also incorrect I will have to try it out again when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not? The key will probably be an empty string, `@""`. Have you tried it?